# PYTHON3: Label overlaps tabs in notebook

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tabs

I'm fairly new to python and tkinter but given the small sample code below why does the label "Hello???" overlap the notebook tabs that are supposedly its parent.

My assumption is that the notebook being the parent of the label would cause row 0 and column 0 ( of the containing Frame ) to be the upper left of the notebook body itself, but it doesn't seem to be the parent, instead self.root appears to be the parent DESPITE the notebook being the object passed as the parent.

Setting the labels grid properties to row=1, column=0 doesn't ( in my understanding rightly ) solve the problem, as row 0 has nothing in it, thus collapses down to nothing. Setting note to row=1, column=0 doesn't appear to do anything either, again for the same reasons. Neither does setting the Page Frame to row=1, column=0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

App.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tkinter import Tk;
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Notebook;
from page import Page;

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent);
        self.root = parent;
        self.root.geometry("450x450+500+500");
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1);
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1);
        self.root.grid();

        note = Notebook(self.root);

        page = Page(note, "pageOne");

        note.add(page, text="Page One");

        note.grid(sticky="NSEW"); #r=0, c=0 of main window


def main():
    root = Tk();
    Application(root);
    root.mainloop();

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Page.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label;

class Page(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        super().__init__(parent);
        self.root = Frame(parent);
        self.name = name;
        self.root.grid(); #r=0, c=0 of notebook interior? 

        Label(self.root, text="Hello???").grid(); #r=0, c=0 also of notebook interior frame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in a `Page` must be in the page. You are creating `self.root` in the parent. That's not how these classes were designed to work. Change that line to:

```
self.root = Frame(self)
```

Though, I don't see a need for `self.root` since `self` is already a `Frame`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still quite new to Python, can you elaborate a bit on the " That's not how these classes were designed to work". I've upvoted and marked as the answer, as changing self.root = Frame(self) in Page.py fixed the issue ( also, removing self.root altogether and just using self ALSO fixed the problem )

Comment: @Akidi: This `Page` class was designed to act as a fully self-contained  unit. When it creates a widget in the parent, it is no longer self-contained.